# Create density bars over line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working with matplotlib and seaborn and would like to generate a plot similar to this one for order book data

[image]

The blue are orders on the book. The shade of these blues represent the depth of the order. The blue line is the highest bid, and the orange is the lowest ask.

The x-axis is time, so vertical lines represent what the book looked like at a particular time.

My dad is a record of all orders placed on the book throughout the day for a particular security.

I'm not really sure how I'd go about generating this graph. I'm pretty savy with data manipulation but I'm not sure how this would be done. It almost looks like a heatplot over the graph? Ideas and suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what we see here ? A heatmap indeed of traded volume per hour&price or does it represent positions (with buy/sell as bands limits) ? Then, is it a volume-weighted average (bought) price ? And is there an additional interval about that line or is it just the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a shot with a few assumptions about the shape of the dataset. Please adjust for your needs.

for a dataset such as

```
time,order,price,n_shares
2021-06-21 10:00:00,sell,48.2,100
2021-06-21 10:00:00,sell,48.3,60
2021-06-21 10:00:00,sell,48.5,10
2021-06-21 10:00:00,buy,48.1,100
2021-06-21 10:00:00,buy,48,60
2021-06-21 10:00:00,buy,47.8,60
2021-06-21 10:00:00,buy,47.2,10
2021-06-21 10:00:01,sell,48.1,100
2021-06-21 10:00:01,sell,48.3,60
2021-06-21 10:00:01,sell,48.5,20
2021-06-21 10:00:01,buy,48,60
2021-06-21 10:00:01,buy,47.8,60
2021-06-21 10:00:01,buy,47.2,80
2021-06-21 10:00:02,sell,48.1,100
2021-06-21 10:00:02,sell,48.3,60
2021-06-21 10:00:02,sell,48.5,20
2021-06-21 10:00:02,buy,48,60
2021-06-21 10:00:02,buy,47.8,60
2021-06-21 10:00:02,buy,47.2,100
2021-06-21 10:00:03,sell,48.2,100
2021-06-21 10:00:03,sell,48.3,60
2021-06-21 10:00:03,sell,48.5,10
2021-06-21 10:00:03,buy,48.1,100
2021-06-21 10:00:03,buy,47.9,60
2021-06-21 10:00:03,buy,47.6,60
2021-06-21 10:00:03,buy,47.1,120
```

You can use something like this to get the gist. Indeed it is a heatmap and lineplot overlay. As index with float doesn't work well, there is some conversion back and forth with integers for the price. Hopefully the comments are enough to understand.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Prices are converted to int not to suffer from float precision
df.price = (df.price*100).astype(int)

min_price = df.price.min()
max_price = df.price.max()

# Make dataframe for lines
mins = df.groupby(["order", "time"]).min().reset_index()
maxs = df.groupby(["order", "time"]).max().reset_index()
buys = maxs.loc[maxs.order == "buy", ["time", "price"]]
sells = mins.loc[mins.order == "sell", ["time", "price"]]
buys["orders"] = "bid"
sells["orders"] = "ask"

orders = pd.concat([buys, sells]).set_index("time")
orders.price = orders.price/100

# Make n_shares matrix for sns.heatmap with a MultiIndex to fill empty with 0
price_idx = np.arange(min_price, max_price + 1)

min_time = df.time.min()
max_time = df.time.max()
time_idx = pd.date_range(min_time, max_time, freq="s")
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)

df = df.set_index(["price", "time"])[["n_shares"]]
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([price_idx, time_idx],
                                       names=["price", "time"])

df = (df
      .reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
      .reset_index()
      .set_index("time"))

df = pd.pivot(df, columns="price")

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.heatmap(ax=ax, data=df.T, cmap="Blues", yticklabels=False,
            cbar_kws={"label": "Shares"})
ax.set_ylabel("Price ($)")
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1, 0.5)

xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=0)
ax.invert_yaxis()

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.lineplot(ax=ax2, data=orders, x="time", y="price", hue="orders",
             palette=sns.color_palette()[3:5])

ax2.set_ylim(min_price/100, max_price/100)
ax2.set_ylabel(None)
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()

plt.show()
```

will give you the backbone of what you need

[image: Orderbook plot]